# How to analyze array for specific value and perform task

Tags: c#

I've created my own class for a book and need to analyze the array for whether or not it contain true or false and then add 5 to anything that contains true. This is the class

```
 class Book
    {
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public string BookName { get; set; }
        public bool Hardcover { get; set; }

        public Book(string bookname, bool hardcover, double price)
        {
            Price = price;
            BookName = bookname;
            Hardcover = hardcover;
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (Hardcover == true)
            {
                return BookName + Price + Hardcover;
            }
            else
            {
                return BookName + Price + Hardcover;
            }

        }
```

This is what i have so far, it is using linq

```
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        List<Book> MyBooks = new List<Book>(); 
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyBooks.Add(new Book("Book 1", false, 5.50));
            MyBooks.Add(new Book("Book 2", false, 5.50));
            MyBooks.Add(new Book("Book 3", false, 5.50));
            MyBooks.Add(new Book("Book 4", false, 5.50));
            MyBooks.Add(new Book("Book 5", true, 5.50));
        }
        private void Grid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button c = (Button)sender;

            List<Book> MyBooks = new List<Book>();

            IEnumerable<String> bookQuery =
                from book in MyBooks
                where book is true
                select book;

            foreach (String p in MyBooks)
            {
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + p.ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
```

thx for the help

Comment: What is `where book is true` meant to mean?

Comment: Your `Book`'s class' properties should be read-only (change them from `{ get; set; }` to `{ get; }`.

Comment: This expression is redundant `p.ToString()` because `p` is already a `String`.

Comment: `foreach (String p in MyBooks)` is invalid. `MyBooks` is a list of `Book`, not a list of `String`.

Comment: Come again?  You want to add 5 to what and when what is true?  Add "5" to the name string at the end?  Add 5 to the price?  Add 5 to the price when hardcover is true makes sense.  But do you want to change the price in the objects or create new objects?

Comment: Do you mean you want to iterate through your list, checking if Hardcover is true & if so then add 5 to the price?

Comment: @Dai: as OP seems to want to update the price, then the Price property cannot be read-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

making some considerable guesses what you mean leads to this:

```
foreach(Book book in MyBooks)
{
    if (book.Hardcover)
       book.Price += 5;
}
```

alternative

```
MyBooks.Where(b => b.Hardcover).ForEach(b => b.Price += 5);
```

Comment: it's what i want but Hardcover isnt accessible since the class is on its own form and hardcover is a true/false option

Comment: not sure what you mean there.  If you have access to a list of Books then you have access to HardCover.

Comment: Book does not contain a definition for 'HardCover' and no accessible extension method 'HardCover' accepting a first argument of type 'Book' could be found

Comment: Try using "Hardcover" rather than "HardCover" - the name is case-sensitive.